# Django templates - include and repeat the block contents

Tags: django, django-templates, include, django-inheritance

In my home.html page, I am trying to include a header.html file along with extending base.html. Following is my code

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
   {% include 'header.html' %}

   # including the block navigation from header.html
   <nav id='header-nav'>{% block nav %} {% endblock %}</nav>

   # including the block image from header.html
   <div id='header-img'>{% block image %} {% endblock %}</div>

   # Reusing the same navigation in footer from header.html
   <div id='footer-nav'>{% block nav %} {% endblock %}</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Home.html looks like the following

```
{% block image %}<h1>I am image</h1>{% endblock %}
{% block nav %}<h1>I am navigation</h1>{% endblock %}
```

However, it returns an error - ''block' tag with name 'nav' appears more than once'.

Why is that? Is there any solutions to this?

Regards

Comment: As per now you can not add two block tags in the same name. Try changing your tag name. Better option is to include all the template that will remain same in every page and only use extend tag in your body.

Answer (score 0):

You included {% block nav %} twice in the same template. That's why it's throwing the error. Maybe you meant to do {% block footer %}?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body %}
   {% include 'header.html' %}

   # including the block navigation from header.html
   <nav id='header-nav'>{% block nav %} {% endblock %}</nav>

   # including the block image from header.html
   <div id='header-img'>{% block image %} {% endblock %}</div>

   # Name this block something else i.e add a new block in header.html
   # and this error should clear up.
   <div id='footer-nav'>{% block footer %} {% endblock %}</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my question is if I can reuse the block nav, more than one time in the template?

Comment: No, as far as I know you can't, and the reason is because the {% block nav %} is substituting new data for whatever data is within the same block in the other template. When you include it twice it causes the template confusion. Since you already have an html div with the id='footer-nav', why not just add another block inside that div in the original template? That would make it clearer for you when extending the template because you know that {% block footer %} refers to the footer div.